# How do you emit to class that has a 'params' constructor?

Tags: reflection, f#, cil, reflection.emit

Here is the definition of my `Package` class:

```
type Package ([<ParamArray>] info : Object[]) =
    do
        info |> Array.iter (Console.WriteLine)

    member this.Count = info.Length
```

and here is the IL, I'm trying:

```
let ilGen = methodbuild.GetILGenerator()

ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, "This is 1")
ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, "Two")
ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, "Three")
ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, typeof<Package>.GetConstructor([|typeof<Object[]>|]))
ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret)
```

but this doesn't seem to work. I tried:

```
ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, typeof<Package>.GetConstructor([|typeof<String>; typeof<String>; typeof<String>|]))
```

a well as:

```
ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, typeof<Package>.GetConstructor([|typeof<Object>; typeof<Object>; typeof<Object>|]))
```

but it just laughs at me. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `[<ParamArray>]` attribute indicates to a compiler that a method accepts a variable number of arguments. However, the CLR doesn't really support `varargs` methods -- it's just syntactic sugar provided by the C#/VB.NET/F# compilers.

Now, if you take away the `[<ParamArray>]`, what are you left with?

```
(info : Object[])
```

That is the signature of the constructor you're trying to call.

So, you'll need to use the `newarr` and `stelem` opcodes to create an array, store the values into it, then call the constructor using the array as *the* argument. This should do what you want (though I haven't tested it):

```
let ilGen = methodbuild.GetILGenerator()

// Create the array
ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_3)
ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Newarr, typeof<obj>)

// Store the first array element
ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Dup)
ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_0)
ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, "This is 1")
ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Stelem_Ref)

// Store the second array element
ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Dup)
ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_1)
ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, "Two")
ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Stelem_Ref)

// Store the third array element
ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Dup)
ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_2)
ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, "Three")
ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Stelem_Ref)

// Call the constructor
ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, typeof<Package>.GetConstructor([|typeof<Object[]>|]))
ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret)
```

NOTE: In this code, I used the `dup` OpCode to avoid creating a local variable to hold the array reference while storing the element values. This is only feasible because this code is fairly straightforward -- I strongly suggest you create a local variable to hold the array reference if you want to build something more complicated.

Comment: BTW, CLR (and C#) does support `varargs`, except it's there just for interop with native varargs methods, it's awkward and nobody uses it.

Comment: @svick Yes, that's true. My point was that there's only one calling convention for managed methods, and it doesn't support `varargs`. Any use of `varargs` with or in a managed method is simply syntactic sugar wrapped around the managed calling convention.